# ProcessMonitor boot logging claims disk is full

Tags: windows-7, debugging

I'm trying to debug an issue where Windows 7 logoff will hang about once in every 5-10 logoffs forcing a hard reboot.  I've installed Process Monitor (v3.2) and am running boot logging to try and find the process that's causing the hang.  The problem I'm having is that once the Procmon.pmb file reaches ~600MB I start getting entries in the log claiming that the disk is full.  The disk has over 10GB of free space.  Does anyone know why Procmon would be thinking the disk is full when it isn't?  I've attached a screenshot of the end of the log.  The specific entry I'm concerned with is:

```
System  4  IRP_MJ_WRITE  C:\Windows\Procmon.pmb  DISK FULL  Offset: 591,370,104, Length: 130,952, Priority: Normal
```

[image]

Comment: Mark Russinovich said, it could be a fragmentation issue. So defrag your HDD and try again

Comment: have you tried to defrag the HDD?

Comment: I did and it didn't have much effect.  This is happening on VDI desktops and our current theory is that it's related to the VMWare View agent.  We upgraded from v6.1 to v6.2 last week and so far it seems to have helped.  With a problem this intermittent it's hard to really know but it looks like it may have been a bug in the v6.1 code.

Comment: ok, thanks for this information. Post your finding as answer.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The problem with posting an answer is I never solved the posted question.  Also, we've started having the hanging problem again so the v6.2 upgrade didn't actually solve anything like I had thought.